# How to write search class?

Tags: php, design-patterns, architecture

I try to write OOP class, that makes searching by some incoming parameters.
I can doing search by location, category, name and others things.
How to make this class more professionally, abstract?

Now I have just one method in the class, that accepts request:

```
private function search($request)
{
    // TODO
}
```

The $request can contains any parameters described above.

I dont like to do:

```
if($request->category){

} else if($request->location){

} else if($request->name){

} ... etc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is get a query-builder (make it or us existing from packagist), because you eventually will want to search by more than one parameter.

As for general organization of the code, I would actually make it more like a service, that is using some type of [table data gateway](https://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/tableDataGateway.html) as a data source. Because I assume, that initially you will use SQL server as your search backend, but if project grows, you should migrate it to something like [SphinxSearch](http://sphinxsearch.com/) or [ElasticSearch](https://www.elastic.co/products/elasticsearch) and having separate abstraction will make it easier to migrate.

Comment: `query-builder ` you mean the design pattern?

Comment: Query builders are not patterns, but libraries.

Comment: I use Laravel. And want to rebuild code not using libraries.

Comment: Laravel does have a [query builder](https://readouble.com/laravel/5.1/en/queries.html). Though, I would probably used [Doctrines DBAL](https://packagist.org/packages/doctrine/dbal) (not the full Doctrine) for this ... creating a hard dependency on a monolithic framework seems somethat shortsighted (especially since Laravle's query builder seems to introduce global state).